# Symfony use a personal bundle in my main bundle

Tags: bundle, symfony

to let you understand what I mean, I will start with an example.
Imagine I have a bundle (MainBundle) which contains my whole besite.
And I want to create a new bundle (CommentBundle) which I will use in my MainBundle to display the comments in each articles.

How can I call the controller of CommentBundle which displays the wanted comments in my MainBundle ?
I mean, it's quite difficult to imagine how that would be possible.

But I heard about the face that bundles were created for this purpose, so I wanted to learn to do it write.

Can someone give me some advices ?

Thank you

Edit :

I did this, but it returned me "Call to a member function has() on null"

```
public function indexAction()
{
        $commentController = new \CommentBundle\Controller\DefaultController();
        $comments = $commentController->indexAction();
        return new Response($comments);
}
```

Comment: Just like you would call any other bundle's controllers? `CommentBundle:List` ie.

Comment: If I want to use the CommentBundle's controller and display it's view in a controller of my MainController, how would I do that ?

Comment: You can use it as you would use any other component, just prefix with `CommentBundle:`

Comment: Okay, I edited the text of my question to show you what I did so you can surely understand what I mean and what I'm doing wrong :) thank you for your help :)